# How can I write my lists in Python to a NetCDF file?

Tags: python, list, file, netcdf

I have a few lists in Python that I am trying to write to NetCDF files, but I am unsure how to get it to work.

An example of how the lists are structured is:

Each list consists of a number of lists itself, say 17, each having 3 elements. The first element species a year, so just an integer or a string, the second element consists of 36 arrays, and the third element consists of 5 arrays.

Based on other guides, I tried to write the code in this manner:

```
fn = 'mean_yearly_list.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(fn, 'w', format='NETCDF4')

year = ds.createDimension('date', None)
lat = ds.createDimension('lat', 36)
clim = ds.createDimension('clim', 5)

years = ds.createVariable('date', 'f4', ('year',))
lats = ds.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('lat',))
clims = ds.createVariable('clim', 'f4', ('clim',))
value1 = ds.createVariable('value_lat', 'f4', ('years', 'lat',))
value2 = ds.createVariable('value_clim', 'f4', ('years', 'clim',))
```

But now I am unsure of how to exactly write my lists/arrays to these variables in the NetCDF file. Does anyone know how this is easiest done? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you have variables/lists with values as yeardata, latdata, climdata,value1data, value2data. Then all you have to do is:

```
years[:] = yeardata;
lats[:] = latdata;
clims[:] = climdata;
value1[:] = value1data;
value2[:] = value2data;

ds.close()
```

As you can already assume, the dimensions of the data has to match with the dimensions in the netCDF file.